# Android sign in with different accounts (Gmail, Twitter, etc)

Tags: android

I developing an app which has the login screen with username and password. Now I want to let the user login with their account with Gmail, Facebook, Twitter and Linked In.  Does anyone have any idea or links that can provide me the description of login with above third party API?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the process of authentication with different services goes like this:

- You request an `AUTH_TOKEN` from the service.
- You send this `AUTH_TOKEN` to your server and either create a new user with all the information that you can possibly get from the service (name, email, location etc.) or you merge it with an existing user if he already exists in the database.
- When the user logs in in the future, you'll know whether his `AUTH_KEY` corresponds to a user in the database or not.

Now for the APIs, for Twitter you can use [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html), for Facebook you can use their [official SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) which are really optimized for a Mobile experience. For the rest, I am not aware of any Android SDK, so you can probably either use [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) as @Darko mentionned or use their [REST APIs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use Spring Social. That has all these account logins and api already setup, you just need the keys from the developer accounts from each service. for which there are also samples and documentation for how to use it. The only drawback would be that it makes the app a bit heavy( about 2 mb), but if you plan to use the API's then its ok.

[Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social)

Here is also the link to the GitHub Sample project.
[SpringAndroidDemo](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-android-samples)