# How to login Gmail in my android project?

Tags: android, email, gmail

I'd like to login Gmail in my android project. Here is what I did:

1. A `EditText` for Gmail account;
2. Another `EditText` for password;
3. A button for login;
4. use `httppost` to submit the user information.

   I always get the response like `ERROR RESPONSE HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed`
   How can I do it?

Comment: A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource;[2] for example, using GET on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a read-only resource.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: this may help you.try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379320/android-sign-in-with-different-accounts-gmail-twitter-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try article on this [url](http://nilvec.com/implementing-smtp-or-imap-xoauth-authentication-in-java/). i think it will helpful to you.